# Norton Equivalent and current convention

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-theory, norton

Consider that we are trying to find the Norton equivalent of a certain circuit . According to my understanding , while finding the short circuit current or the Norton current , we should point it downward across the Short circuit terminal. But if we find that the actual direction of the Norton current is upward , should we in this case also reverse the current source direction of the Norton equivalent circuit to point upward ?  If yes , then why ?

Comment: Yes. Negative curret through current source will be pretty confusing. Always show positive current and reverse the arrow direction if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you find that the short circuit current is negative then the short circuit current actually flows "upward" (assuming the standard way problems are drawn with two relevant nodes aligned one above the other). And if the short circuit current actually flows upward then the Norton source must be oriented pointing down, so that the current will again flow out of the lower terminal and into the upper terminal.

Maybe it is easier to think of the Thevenin equivalent situation. If you find that the open circuit voltage is negative, then you need to reverse the orientation of the Thevenin voltage source so that the open circuit voltage is negative in the Thevenin equivalent, just like it was in the original circuit.